Imaginary Units in the Pythagorean Theorem
Are there any exceptions to the Pythagorean Theorem?
I ask this after seeing the triangle with sides i, $1$, and $0$. Sure, this triangle checks out with the Pythagorean Theorem ($i^2+1^2=0^2$), but it makes no sense as the hypotenuse is shorter than both legs. Is this an exception to the theorem or are imaginary units simply not compatible with Euclidean geometry?

Short answer: standard Euclidean geometry is necessarily real. If you want complex geometry, there are different ways to do that, leading to different concepts. One of them  is obtained by simply replacing real numbers with complex numbers, and in this case line segments can have zero length, similar to Minkowsky spaces.

"as the hypotenuse is shorter than both legs"  Not really.  There is no order on complex numbers and zero is not shorter than $i$.  And zero is smaller than $1$ only in the real order.   .... But in general the pyth th. as about the lengths of the sides of a triangle-- not the sides themselve.  A length is a distance and a distance is non-negative real number. How did you have a triangle with side of length $i$?  In what sense did you mean?  We can't even have a triangle with negative sides. (Note: coordinates are not lengths)

"after seeing the triangle with sides i, 1, and 0"  Where did you see such a triangle?

For complex numbers, the Pythagorean theorem is
$$
|a|^2 + |b|^2 = |c|^2 .
$$
In case $a,b,c$ are real, this becomes the usual formula
$$
a^2+b^2=c^2
$$
